# How will the Camera Intrinsics change if an image is cropped/resized?

Tags: computer-vision, camera, camera-calibration

I have a recorded camera ROS bag file from a Realsense camera. The camera intrinsics for the recorded setting in already know. The initial resolution of the image is 848*480. Because of some visual obstruction in the FOV of the camera I would like to crop out the top of the image so it doesn't gets detected with Visual SLAM Algorithm I am using.
Since SLAM is heavily dependent on the Camera Intrinsics, I would like to know **how will the camera parameters `f_x`, `f_y`, `c_x` and `c_y` change for :**

1. Cropped Image
2. Resized Image (Image Scaling only)

[image: Image Size Changes]

There is no skew involved in the original camera parameters. 
Will the new pricipal point `c_x` also change as `Cropped_image_width`?
I am bit confused as to **how to calculate the new camera parameters ? Am I correct in assuming the following for the Case 1 - Cropped Case :**

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cropping:

- `cx,cy` reduced by the amount of pixels cropped off the **left/top**. Cropping off of right/bottom edges has no effect.

Scaling:

- `fx,fy` are multiplied by the scaling factor
- `cx,cy` are multiplied by the scaling factor

Remember, the principal point need not be in the center of the image.

Assuming top left image origin. Off-by-one/half (pixel) errors to be checked carefully against the specific scaling algorithm used, or just ignored.

Comment: Thank you. Just to clarify .
For `f_x` since the focal length of the camera remains same, in cropped case, the  pixel size(Sensor Size / no. of pixels) will also remain same so no changes. In case of scaling pixel size will change so it will be multiplied by scaling factor. 
For the principal point, it is just the measure of projection center (center of camera frustum [Camera Intrinsics](https://ksimek.github.io/2013/08/13/intrinsic/] ) from the top left corner so cropping top or left areas affects it. In case of scaling, the image left and top edge itself changes position so the scaling

Answer (score 0):

For the case no. 1, cx is the same as the original image, but cy changes as newHeight/2.

For the case no. 2, f changes as fxscale.