# New Pinhole Camera Intinsics Matrix for the Cropped Image

Tags: python, camera, camera-calibration

I give the following example to illustrate my question: suppose I have a camera intrinsics matrix that follows the pin-hole camera model, and its intrinsics matrix has the following structure:

```
 ori_intrinsics= [[fx, 0,  cx,],
                  [0,  fy, cy],
                   [0, 0, 1]]
```

I also know the image it can generate of size `[ori_width, ori_height]`. Then now I crop the image in the image position `[ori_left, ori_top, ori_right, ori_bottom]`. Now I have a new image. Then my question is as follows:  image now I have a similar camera(the same pin-hole camera) and it will generate the same new image without any cropping operation as I did before. What will be the camera intrinsics for this camera?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How will the Camera Intrinsics change if an image is cropped/resized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74749690/how-will-the-camera-intrinsics-change-if-an-image-is-cropped-resized)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cropping an image does not affect focal length, so no change to `fx, fy`. The only thing that will change is cx and cy, and this needs to be adjusted based on how much you have cropped from top-left.

If you crop by `L, T`, then:

- `c_newx = cx - L` and
- `c_newy = cy - T`